# How to compare logarithms with different bases?

Tags: logarithms

I need to know how i should compare logarithms with different bases

Eg:

- $\log_4 1/15$
- $\log_3 (1/2)$
- $\log_5(1/30)$

Witch is greater?  I need valid reasoning and proof if possible! Thanks.

Comment: Convert them to a common base.. then note that logarithm function is increasing if base $> 1$

Comment: how can i convert bases 4,3 and 5 to a common base?

Comment: Use base converter formula

Comment: You can put the examples that you gave in order by approximating their values. For example, 15 lies between 4 and 16, so log 15 to base 4 lies between 1 and 2, so log 1/15 to base 4 lies between -1 and -2 etc.

Comment: that can work but if numbers were very close together .this might not help right?and i have to convert bases ?is there any other way to compare these kind of logarithms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play around with the values. Estimate them. See what happens. For example:

Let's see... $\log_4 (1/15)$.... hmmm.... well, $\log_4(1/16) = -2$... and $\log_4(1/4)=-1$.... so, $\log_4(1/15)$ is between $-2$ and $-1$.... okay, that's pretty good.

How about this one? $\log_3(1/2)$... hmmm..... $\log_3(1/3)=-1$,... and, hey I see it... $\log_3(1)=0$, so $\log_3(1/2)$ is between $-1$ and $0$, so 
$$\log_4(1/15) < -1 < \log_3(1/2)
$$

Comment: ...hmm... hmm.. :)

Comment: hmmm that was great .thank you so much :)